# How do I know the string inputs accepted by a "function?" parameter?

Tags: python

*(Apologies for the unclear title. Please bare with me for I am completely new to coding and I do not know many terminologies.)*

What I mean by the title is I wish to know the inputs accepted by (Not sure what it is called... functions?)

For example:

```
cube = bpy.context.active_object
cube.keyframe_insert("data_path", frame=0)
```

This is one of the first few lines of code I have learned. What I wish to learn is...

**(1)** what is `keyframe_insert()` called? is it a function?

**(2)** I have partially read the Blender Docs regarding this "function?" and have known its parameters, particularly the `data_path` which accepts string arguments like `"location"` and `"rotation"` (that is all I know for now).  What I wish to learn is, how can I know the other arguments accepted by this parameter? Is there like a book that I could reference to? The Blender API Docs only states the parameters and the definition but not the accepted arguments.

The Blender API Docs is like a labyrinth for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Although your questions relate to Blender API functions, I'd strongly suggest that you learn the basics of python itself first. There are lots of online tutorials about python. [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) is the official Python start page for beginners and [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/scripting/introduction.html) is the Blender manual start page about using python in Blender.